# Flowjs - method with generic type argument is not accepting argument when being called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm having trouble understanding why my mockPG object literal is not being accepted as an argument to my generic  registerDataService method call.

failing here:

```
registerDataService(mockPG)
```

The error i'm getting back:

**Cannot call registerDataService with mockPG bound to pgPool because object literal [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVHN6.png) is incompatible with T [2] in type argument R [3] of the return value of property query**

Any pointer here would be great.

**My Code**

**Register Data Service unit test**

```
  const mockPG = {
       query: (sql: string, args: Array<?string>) => new Promise((resolve) 
        => {
            resolve({
             rows: [
             {
              usernameAvailable: false,
              alternativeUserName: ['ray1', 'ray_22', 'ray_786']
             }
            ]
           });
          }).then((res) => res)
       };
  }

registerDataService(mockPG)  //  **<-- error here with mockPG:**
```

[image]

**RegisterDataService File**

```
type pgPoolType<T> = {
  query: <T>(sql: string, args: Array<?string>) => Promise<T>
};

const validateNewUserNameAsync = (userName: string, pgPool: pgPoolType<pgPoolQueryResponse<row>>): 
                                 Promise<validateNewUserNameAsyncResponse> => {}

const registerUserAsync = (userDetails: ud, userStatusId: string, authUrl: string,             
                          pgPool: pgPoolType<pgPoolQueryResponse<registernRow>>
                          ): Promise<registerUserAsyncResponse> => { }


module.exports = (pgPool: pgPoolType<any>) => ({
   validateNewUserNameAsync: (userName: string) => validateNewUserNameAsync(userName, pgPool)
   registerUserAsync: (userDetails: ud, userStatusId: string, authUrl: string) => 
                       registerUserAsync(userDetails, userStatusId, authUrl, pgPool)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to get this to work.

I made a mistake in the query function:

```
 type pgPoolType<T> = {
   query: <T>(sql: string, args: Array<?string>) => Promise<T>
 };
```

by removing the t at the start of the query function, as i'm using  from pgPoolType instead.

```
   type pgPoolType<T> = {
       query: (sql: string, args: Array<?string>) => Promise<T>
   };
```